# Mercurial/Hg commit message prefixed with current branch directory

Tags: netbeans, mercurial, branch, dvcs

We are using Mercurial with cloned repositories for our "branches". The "branch" in each clone is "default".

The structure is:

```
repos/Test
repos/Trunk
repos/Live
repos/NewFeature
```

When finished with work in Trunk the changes are pulled into the Test clone. As each commit is done to `default` there is now way I can see to see where the changes were originally made, i.e. in the Trunk or the Test repo.

I would like to know how to automatically prefix each commit message with say `[Trunk]` or `[Test]` — then the logs would be easier to view.

I would like this to happen when committing both from the cmd line and from Netbeans.

Answer (score 3):

There's no option for this and no existing Mercurial extension as far as I know.

However, I would consider switching to [named branches](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/tasks/) instead: that way you get the current branch name embedded directly in the meta data in the changeset. Changelog viewers will generally display the branch name somewhere prominently in their UI so that it's easy to see where each changeset belongs.

Comment: I did initially think about that, but as we have to develop concurrently on 3 or 4 branches I think the cloned approach is better for us. 

We have Jenkins working with this approach and the only thing which I would like is the commit message prefix. 

I think I will investigate a pre commit hook...

Answer (score 1):

We use a script containing this:

```
import re,os,sys,mercurial,repo

def prefix_commit_message(repo, **kwargs):
 commitctx = repo.commitctx

 def rewrite_ctx(ctx, error):
  branch_name = repo.root.split("/")[5]
  old_text = ctx._text
 ctx._text = "["+branch_name+"] "+old_text

 return commitctx(ctx, error)
```

And the .hgrc is this:

```
$ cat ~/.hgrc
[ui]
username = Ian Wood

[hooks]
precommit = python:~/Development/repository/prepend-branch-name.py:prefix_commit_message
```

Answer (score 0):

The mercurial wiki contains a number of suggestions on how to set up a [commit message template](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CommitMessageTemplate). That takes care of the command line.

As for Netbeans, I don't know whether it will let you do this out of the box. You could always [write a plug-in](http://wiki.netbeans.org/IntroNetBeansPluginDev).

Comment: Thanks - will take a look at those suggestions.